# How to find out the compress happen when some force act on water/oil/air?

Tags: water, density

I need to do some calculation to find out whether my design works. I may use oil/water/air in my pneumatic cylinder (or you can call it hydraulic cylinder). Assume I have just a cylinder and I put oil into the chamber to raise a weight. My question is how much of volume will reduce when the weight is x kg (Let assumes x = 20). Also what if I change the oil to water or air.

From my knowledge air is easier to calculate, because I can use the ideal gas law. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air is by ideal gas law, for water, you need the [bulk modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) which is $2.2 \times 10^9$ Pascals. This means that at a pressure P Pascals slightly more than atmospheric pressure, you reduce the volume by P divided by this number.

According to [this web page](http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=272324), oil has a bulk modulus of roughly 200,000 Psi, which is about $1.5 \times 10^9$ Pascals.

Comment: I love your answer. It is simple enough for non-expert (like me) to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must specify wether the temperature is constant or if there is some heat exchange. Then you just have to use the isothermal compressibility or adiabatic compressibilty factor.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility